# Airport Extreme port forward from 8888 to 80 not working

Tags: apache, networking, webserver, port

I'm trying to port forward outside port 8888 to inside port 80 and it is just dealing me fits.

I have this working with ssh, forwarding port 22222 to port 22 of a machine on the internal network. No problems there.

Now I want to setup a web server for testing purposes and I want to forward port 8888 to port 80 on the test web server. I don't want to forward 80 to 80 as there is already a site on a different machine that needs to stay working. Here's what I've done:

- Description: web_dev
- Public UDP Ports:
- Public TCP Ports: 8888
- Private IP Address: 10.0.1.216
- Private UDP Ports:
- Private TCP Ports: 80

Should this not do what I want? When I try to access the server from outside of the network using a URL like http://example.com:8888 my browser instead displays the "main" site that is already being forwarded from port 80 to 80 (i.e. the non-test site). Weird.

They are separate sites on separate servers.

Site 1 (the main site) is at 10.0.1.2 and the router is forwarding port 80 to 80 for that one. Works fine.

Site 2 (the test site) is at 10.0.1.216 and the router is forwarding port 8888 to 80 for that. This is the one that isn't working the way I want. The server works fine on the internal network (i.e. `http://10.0.1.216` gives me the page I'm expecting).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for setting me straight.

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

Meh... I couldn't ever get it to do what I wanted.

So, my solution was to setup a VM instance of Ubuntu with nginx as a reverse proxy server and have it direct requests for me. Been meaning to do it for some time anyway - this provided the catalyst to move forward.

Seems to be working so far.

-Matt